# Machine learning model when important feature is commonly missing

Tags: machine-learning, missing-data

Suppose I would like to develop a machine learning model from 10 datasets to predict a clinical diagnosis (diagnosed or not). After checking the data, all of the outcome and feature data are similarly distributed in the datasets and it is reasonable to combine these datasets.

However, they are discrepant one one feature: half of the datasets collected x-ray data, and the other half didn't due to logistical constraints (ie, no x-ray machine, no radiologist available, etc.). This is also realistic in real-world application, about half of people wont have an x-ray. However, if obtained, x-ray results are important in the diagnosis and influential in previous models that incorporate these data.

Is it possible to develop an ML model that would reflect this situation? Would an ensemble model that combines two independently trained models (represented in the below figure) be a reasonable approach?

[image]

Comment: *Why* half of the people don't have X-rays?

Comment: Good point - due to availability of the x-ray machine and limited resources in the settings from where the data were collected

Comment: Fun question (+1). I don't think an ensembling approach is directly applicable as I see a lot of issue with the two sub-samples being different. Please see my answer below where I expand on this issue further and offer an alternative based on transfer learning. Let me know if you need any clarification, I appreciate it is not a yes/no answer post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think at this point we are faced with two distinct deployment environments and as such two models are warranted. It is tempting to consider some multiple-model, two-staging, stacking, ensembling, mixing, etc. methodology but they more I think of the setting the more I think it is fraught with modelling caveats. Some of these caveats are the following:

1. The missingness of X-ray is not "completely-at-random" between the two (sub-)samples so direct imputation of X-ray features can be problematic. The two subsamples can still have different dynamics and almost certainly different unmeasured confounders (e.g. access to X-rays).
2. There is an implicit underlying assumption in your commentary that "*all patients who have access to an X-ray machine and a radiologist get an X-ray*"; I would question how realistic it is. Likely, a doctor thinking that a case is not too severe might not request a diagnostic X-ray (due on cost, time, work-load, etc.).
3. Complete case analysis (CCA) can be biased when that the chance of being a complete case depends on the observed values of the outcome. The two prior points strongly suggest we are in this situation so we cannot go for that.

My suggestion would be to mimic [transfer learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_learning). Somewhat informally, in transfer learning, we use a pre-trained model as the starting point for (usually) another task where we try to take advantage of learned features and/or outputs of the pre-trained model.  [*Transfer learning for non-image data in clinical research: A scoping review*](https://journals.plos.org/digitalhealth/article?id=10.1371/journal.pdig.0000014) (2022) by Ebbehoj et al. give a very relevant overview.

A simple approach I can suggest would start by splitting our data in two sub-samples. One with and one without X-rays *access*, let's call them subsamples $A$ and $B$ respectively.
We would then use subsample $B$ to create a few models for their respective outcome; we pick the best one, say $M_B$. We report how well we do in our diagnostic task (maybe we have a holdout from $B$, maybe we present bootstrap estimates, repeated $k$-fold). Effectively this is how good we do in our "large training" set from a "resource poor" environment.

We have not touched sub-sample $A$ until now. For the next step we use $M_B$ to create risk estimates for the instances in sub-sample $A$. These estimates can now be used as a new feature to build our model $M_A$ that uses the X-ray info together with everything else to give risk estimates. Similar with the step above, we report how good we do in our "smaller calibration" set within this "resource rich" environment. We note here that this calibration also allows us to account for potential [domain shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_adaptation#Domain_shift) (change in the data distribution between the two sub-samples).

Notice that in the above approach we never use model subsamples $A$ and $B$ at the same time. In a sense we perform a "pseudo"-transfer learning; $M_B$ gives us our hidden feature(s) and we "calibrate" our performance based on our new sample. The narrative between what the two model do is also quite simple: $M^B$ gives us our risk estimates in a resource-poor environment and $M_A$ gives us our risk estimates in a resource-rich environment by adjusting the risk presented by $M_B$.

I recently read the paper [*What is being transferred in transfer learning?*](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2020/hash/0607f4c705595b911a4f3e7a127b44e0-Abstract.html) (2020) by Neyshabur et al., it focuses on Computer Vision but it is quite readable and easy to understand how it can be applicable in other areas too.

Comment: This is a wonderful and thoughtful explanation - thank you! I was not familiar with transfer learning so it is an exciting area to investigate. Thanks again!

Comment: Pleasure @jpsmith! Transfer learning has revolutionised computer vision/imaging applications and using it in other context is only make it more impactful. Side note: When building $M_A$ in my example you might even use actual DNNs trained on medical imaging datasets to extract relevant features/segmentations (looking up the terms "deep learning model chest X-ray classification" returns ten of thousands of hits on Google Scholar). That way you "*put some real transfer learning to our approximate transfer learning*" (the combination of "dad" and "AI" humour is shocking, I will show myself out.).